# what percentiles metrics reflect your app performance?

Tags: performance, metrics, percentile

I've been recently introduced to the percentile metrics for measuring different aspects of your application's efficiency (i.e: like p50, p90, and p99 latency, etc..)
I'm not sure why are p50s used, like this kind of metrics is sort of vague and doesn't provide much of information in case you wanted to measure your app's efficiency.
I think this might be a broad question, but what kind of percentiles reflect the most about the efficiency of your app ?

Answer (score 8):

To answer your question, I'll provide some background about mean/average.
Example,  I have few samples (response time a web request) 1,2,1,3,2,2,1,3,2,40

If I take mean/average then it is : 5.7

Here you will say that my average response time is 5.7 which doesn't represent real case. here you can see most samples are below 3 but because of one **outlier** your average changed from 1.9 to 5.7.
Problem with mean/average is, sometimes it doesn't represent actual results

Percentiles help us to provide actual picture. Here if you take 90 percentile, value is 3. So you can say that, 90% of my responses are below 3.
which is representing real case or close to your actual mean.

I hope you understand why percentiles are used.

In practice, generally 90th, 95th (mostly) and 99th percentiles are used in performance measurements to find out actual values by removing outliers.

There is no straightforward answer to which percentile to be used in which case because that varies from application to application, data modelling, available samples etc.

In practice 90th and 95th percentiles are used in most cases to see application performance because that gives you a 90% or 95% confidence level which is enough in most cases.

Comment: I get the idea behind percentiles and how averages are the worst thing to use, but this isn't a question about what percentile means, rather, it's about what types of percentiles to use ?
I've seen metrics of 95th, 99th, and sometimes 99.9th percentiles, but I can't find in which cases to use which one.
It seems like anything below 99th is ignoring a good amount of info

Comment: There is no thumb rule or answer to 'Which percentile to be used in which case' because it depends on lot of things like your data model, available samples, expected confidence interval. But as I have already said, 90th or 95th suffice most cases.

Answer (score 2):

Which percentile to use is depended on your Service Level Objectives hence most of the times falls into business objectives.

Let's say you are building/maintaining a mature e-commerce website and you have 2 services: 1) retrieving goods record `goodsRenderingService` 2) registering new customer `registeringService`.

After talking with your product owner or project manager or whatever, you agreed that there wouldn't be too many customers registering at the same time and it's fine if it took up to 5 seconds to register. This objective can be quantified as: `registeringService` takes up to 5 seconds for 75% of the concurrent requests.

But it's a different story when customers are browsing goods - they cannot wait more than 1 second for the goods to be rendered and that's the core of your business. So you decide it gotta be less than 1 second 99.9% of the time. Even by that, if you have 1 million customers browsing the website at the same time, you'll still likely to lose 1,000 impatient customers (1,000,000 * 0.1%). But given the scale of the business and the cost, your CTO decided it's ok to use 99.9% percentile.

So in short, there's no principle which percentile you should use without business evaluation. But in general, if you want to find how your data is distributed, I always use 25%, 50%, 75%, 99%, and standard deviation. But it bounded with other factors such as business requirement (you wouldn't set the same percentile and objective in e-commerce website and community library system), costs (requirements in higher percentile usually comes with exponentially higher costs), and etc.

Maybe it doesn't fully answered your questions, but hope it helps.